# How to access user control properties from page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having problem in accessing user control properties from page.
I have usercontrol on master page with some properties,but i am unable to access them from the codebehind of the page which uses that master page.i want to set some properties of usercontrol on page load.Can anyone suggest how can i access them from page.

E.G.

**User Control**

`ucTabSystem.ascx` has following properties:

```
 public string TabName
    {
        get { return _tabName; }
        set { _tabName = value; }
    }
 public string TabUrl
    {
        get { return _tabUrl; }
        set { _tabUrl = value; }
    }
```

**Master Page**

`InHouseTPAMaster.master` has this user control in it.

**ClaimHomePage.aspx**

Uses Master page `InHouseTPAMaster.master` and i want to set usercontrol properties in page load of this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two methods. 
The first is by using Page.Master.FindControl('controlID'). Then you can cast it to the type of your user control. The second method is by adding a <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="" TypeName=""%> tag to your aspx page. In the VirtualPath add the virtual path to the master page, and the class in the TypeName. You can then access everything with intellisense

Comment: Thanks for reply...i got it worked using virtual path but in tedious way...i have created same properties in master page which in turn call properties of usercontrol...and using virtualpath(using Master) in pages, i am setting master page property in page now....Thanks for the help..:)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way to set your properties...

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Tab" TagName="sys" Src="ucTabSystem.ascx" %>

<tab:sys id="mysys" runat="server" TabName="xxxxx"    TabUrl = "yyyy"  />
```

Comment: Thanks for reply...Your code will work when usercontrol is directly placed on page itself but But my user control is already been registered on master page and is being used in multiple pages,i want to set property of user control on each page which uses that master page...

Comment: OK ,I see.  you can try this in your page_load event ...  ((ucTabSystem)Page.Master.FindControl("ucTabSystem")).TabName = "xxxx" ;

Comment: Cannt found it ? Or , Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("ucTabSystem")  ?

Comment: Thanks for your effort..but i somehow got it worked using Virtualpath.Thanks buddy i appreciate your help..:)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a public interface with two properties - TabName and TabUrl in separate code file.

```
public interface  IUserControl
{
    string TabName{get;set;}
    string TabUrl {get;set;}
}
```

Implements the IUserControl interface to UserControl class. For instance, I've `MyUserControl` and its code-behind is:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl , IUserControl 
{
    public string TabName
    {
        get { return ViewState["TabName"] == null ? string.Empty : ViewState["TabName"].ToString(); }
        set { ViewState["TabName"]= value; }
    }
    public string TabUrl
    {
        get { return ViewState["TabUrl"] == null ? string.Empty : ViewState["TabUrl"].ToString(); }
        set { ViewState["TabUrl"] = value; }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Register `MyUserControl` in MasterPage and it has following markup in it.(master page)

```
 <%@ Register src="MyUserControl.ascx" tagname="MyUserControl" tagprefix="uc1" %>
 ......
 <uc1:MyUserControl ID="MyUserControl1" runat="server" />
```

In Page_Load event (or any other) handler of aspx page (Which is a content page of *said* master page).

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IUserControl control = Master.FindControl("MyUserControl1") as IUserControl;
        control.TabName = "Something";
        control.TabUrl = "http://www.example.com";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply...i had tried the same ways of findcontrol from page before with no help...but i got it worked using virtual path...by which i was able to get intellegence and got it worked...anyways thanks for youe help..:)